# Get ActiveX Object properties

Tags: c#, vb6, automation, activex

In short: I have a VB6 form with ActiveX control that contains buttons, and I would like to create automatic tool that can click this buttons using C#.
I tried to use reflection for this issue, but I cannot access the form.
The general direction I was suggested was to use window API to access the form, but it seem very "expensive" solution.

Does anyone familiar with this subject?
Thank you

Comment: This no doubt a control that's owned by another process.  Yes, that's going to be expensive, you'll have to invest a lot of time into learning the Windows API.  You cannot access the control directly, only the windows that it creates.  Some don't, especially VB6 ones.  Start with Spy++ to see what's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use [AutomationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.aspx) from .net?

To test this:

1. download [UiSpy.zip](http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2009/09/15/uispy-ndash-download-it-here.aspx) link taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848721/where-do-i-get-ui-spy)
2. Get the form open, activate the hover mode. If you "see" the button it should be easy to use ] AutomationElement to actually send a click to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about sending/hooking window messages (e.g. sending WM_MOUSEDOWN or WM_MOUSEMOVE)? Short/simplified example can be found [here](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/10/605.aspx).

Comment: this solution is not good for me because I would like to also access the ActiveX object, in order to also get its properties

Comment: So we're not talking about clicking buttons only? Or is it just about picking dropdown values or putting text into input boxes? You should add this to your question (what exactly you're trying to do).

Comment: The first and most needed step is to perform button click according to its pixel position (not by triggering the click event), but I would like to know also how I can handle other controls (comboboxes, grids etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to automate the UI for testing, I would suggest TestComplete from SmartBear Software which can directly access your VB6 forms, controls and properties. They're basically hooking into the process and accessing the "Forms" object and "Screen" object to get access to the loaded forms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The base of my question is the fact that I want to replace my current automation tool (QTP) in my own dedicated framework. Since I'm testing my company's application I do not need automatic tool as generic as TestComplete or QTP.